# How do i build a discord app in heroku if the discord.py 2.0 and pycord 2.0 isn't available for download offcially

Tags: python, github, heroku, deployment, module

```
Downloading discord_components-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discord.py==2.0.0a3575+g45d498c (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.10.0, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 0.14.3, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.16.3, 0.16.4, 0.16.5, 0.16.6, 0.16.7, 0.16.8, 0.16.9, 0.16.10, 0.16.11, 0.16.12, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3)
   ERROR: No matching distribution found for discord.py==2.0.0a3575+g45d498c
```

So I am trying to deploy a discord bot in heroku which uses discord.py 2.0 and pycord.py 2.0 and higher which i downloaded from discord but while building it shows this error because it isn't officially available and we need to install from github so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using a `requirements.txt` file or a `Pipfile`?

Comment: requirements.txt